# List view fields from APEX or LWC controller

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view

I want to get the columns of a listview to use them in a generic data table!
Can I get a listView's fields using apex or LWC?

Comment: Note: i want to get only the columns not the records !

Comment: I think you can achieve this using lightning data tables. Please check out this link and let me know whether this is what you expected.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getListUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui) to get the fields and records for a given list view. It contains everything you need to build your UI into a lightning-datatable or custom table, depending on your needs. Do note you'll still end up getting the first page of records, but you can ignore them if you don't need them.